# CSS Issue, User profile on top bar, on User Page

Tags: bug, design

There's a spacing issue on the user profile section of the top bar (User Icon, Rep, Badge Counts), when on the user profile page. It only happens on M&TV & Meta.M&TV, no other Stack.

Every other page on M&TV shows it fine. For some reason, the User Profile page adds a margin to the badge icon. 2px left 6px right. It throws everything off.

computed Css rules in `all.css`
`.user-page .badge1, .user-page .badge2, .user-page .badge3`
`margin: 0 2px 0 6px`

Please fix/remove/make it like every other page, which lacks that.

Comment: Are you actually talking about this thing: [/users and profile pages (/users/…) space the link to the current profile (in the top bar) differently](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1652/49)?

Comment: Yes... a year to fix a css issue smh